# One-to-one mapping in S#arp Architecture

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture, automapping

There's a distinct smell of burned out circuits coming from my head, so forgive my ignorance.

I'm trying to setup a one-to-one relationship (well, let Automapper do it) in S#arp Architecture.

I have

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual Basket Basket { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }  
    ...
}

public class Basket : Entity
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }  
    ...
}

public class Profile : Entity
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And my db schema is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ...

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profiles](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserFk] [int] NULL,
    ...

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Baskets](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserFk] [int] NULL,
    ...
```

When I run the unit test CanConfirmDatabaseMatchesMappings in MappingIntegrationTests I get the following error

> NHibernate.ADOException : could not
>   execute query ...
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException :
>   Invalid column name 'ProfileFk'.
>   Invalid column name 'BasketFk'.

and the sql it's trying to execute is

```
SELECT TOP 0
    this_.Id AS Id6_1_ ,
    ..
    user2_.ProfileFk AS ProfileFk9_0_ ,
    user2_.BasketFk AS BasketFk9_0_
FROM
    Profiles this_
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Users user2_
        ON this_.UserFk = user2_.Id
```

So it's looking for a ProfileFk and BasketFk field in the Users table. 
I haven't setup any customer override mappings and as far as I can see I've followed the default conventions setup in S#.

The two other mappings for IList Orders and Roles seem to map fine. So I'm guessing that it've missed something for setting up a one-to-one relationship.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. This is really an NHibernate problem to solve with Fluent NHibernate syntax, but it happens to be relevant for S#.

Background reading: [NHibernate Mapping](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/19/nhibernate-mapping-ltone-to-onegt.aspx)  and [Fluent NHibernate HasOne](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#HasOne_.2F_one-to-one)

What you do is override the mapping for User and give it two .HasOne mappings. Then set a unique reference to the user on the Profile and Basket class:

```
public class UserMap : IAutoMappingOverride<User>
    {
        #region Implementation of IAutoMappingOverride<User>
        /// <summary>
        /// Alter the automapping for this type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mapping">Automapping</param>
        public void Override(AutoMapping<User> mapping)
        {
            mapping.HasOne(u => u.Profile);
            mapping.HasOne(u => u.Basket);
        }
        #endregion
    }

public class ProfileMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Profile>
    {
        #region Implementation of IAutoMappingOverride<Profile>
        /// <summary>
        /// Alter the automapping for this type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mapping">Automapping</param>
        public void Override(AutoMapping<Profile> mapping)
        {
            mapping.References(p => p.User).Unique().Column("UserFk");
        }
        #endregion
    }

public class BasketMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Basket>
    {
        #region Implementation of IAutoMappingOverride<Basket>
        /// <summary>
        /// Alter the automapping for this type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mapping">Automapping</param>
        public void Override(AutoMapping<Basket> mapping)
        {
            mapping.References(b => b.User).Unique().Column("UserFk");
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

As a side note, at the time of writing this, NHibernate 3 has just been released. There's a great book out called [NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book) which I've just bought and it looks extremely useful for working with S#.

Comment: ... and I've got the feeling that you probably don't even need the .HasOne mappings (because really these are many-to-one relationships)